# Can I reduce wire gauge downstream of a limited-current relay?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I am planning to add an [ICM102F](https://www.icmcontrols.com/product/icm102f/) relay to a switched circuit which powers a circulation pump.

That pump is served by a non-dedicated 20A breaker and run with 12AWG MC cable.
The relay is rated at 1.5A (which is plenty for my pump) and its wire leads are 16awg.

With 12awg coming into the box, connecting to 16awg in the relay, am I still required to return to 12awg from the relay to the pump? Or may I downsize the wire due to the relay rating? (Perhaps to 14awg?)

I'm curious because any load that's too large for the 14awg is also too large for the relay and its 16awg wiring.

Comment: *Maybe* if you added a fuse or breaker of lower rating protecting that part of the circuit, though for household line voltage wiring outside of fixtures and devices 14 AWG is the minimum.

Comment: Usually a manufacturer will have their devices tested(UL/etc) to be safe with smaller gauge wire.  For the common folk adding wire/cable they need to go by the minimum for that breaker.  For a 20 amp breaker that is 12 gauge

Answer (score 2):

Any wire you add between the devices has to meet the required ampacity for the circuit. The manufacturers of relays and pumps get to use thin wire because they test for UL listing with thin wire. In many cases, their wire acts as a fuse of sorts. Your added wiring is not expected to act as a fuse, so it gets to hand off that duty to the Over-Current Protection Device, usually the circuit breaker. Wire between your devices with 12 gauge, assuming no derating and a typical 20 amp circuit.

Comment: So I am required to go 12 > 16 > 12?

Comment: Yes you are required. You want that short length of 16 frying in the box rather than some bit of wire elsewhere.

Comment: Yes. Anything you wire has to suited to the ampacity of the circuit.